# Problema al cargar información en select Materialize 1.0.0 y Angular

Tags: angular, materialize, html-select, angular10

Me encuentro usando Materialize.CSS con angular.
Tengo información que carga un select con información de un servicio.
El componente es el que sigue:

```
...
comboNivelEstres: Combo[] = [];

constructor(
    private _comboService: ComboService,
    private _datosAntropometricosService: DatosAntropometricosService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit():void  {
    this._comboService.obtenerComboNivelEstres()
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          this.comboNivelEstres = resp.datos
            .map(nivelEstres => {
              return {nombre: nivelEstres, valor: nivelEstres};
            });
          M.AutoInit();
        },
        (respError) => {
          console.warn(respError);
        }
      );
}
...
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-field">
  <select id="nivel-estres">
    <option
      *ngFor="let e of comboNivelEstres"
      [value]="e.valor"
    >
     {{ e.nombre }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <label for="nivel-estres">Nivel de estrés</label>
</div>
```

Sin embargo, el select queda vacío (los option si se completan, el `ul` de materialize no). Al parecer es porque no se actualiza el select al terminar de cargar la información. He probado con `M.AutoInit()` y no se actualiza.

Tal vez me esté equivocando de método para actualizar los select. Esperaría algo como `M.updateSelect()` para que se refresque con los nuevos option cargados.

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa porque se llama la función `M.AutoInit();` antes de que Angular haya renderizado el html.

Puedes agregar un `setTimeout()` para esperar que Angular renderize el nuevo html.

```
ngOnInit():void  {
    this._comboService.obtenerComboNivelEstres()
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          this.comboNivelEstres = resp.datos
            .map(nivelEstres => {
              return {nombre: nivelEstres, valor: nivelEstres};
            });
          setTimeout(() => M.AutoInit(), 100)
        },
        (respError) => {
          console.warn(respError);
        }
      );
}
```